# The static field View.GONE should be accessed in a static way

Tags: android, constants, android-view

There is an error in this condition `if((detail.VISIBLE) && (pod.GONE) && (photo.GONE))`
that "The static field `View.GONE` should be accessed in a static way"

...

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, 
                        float velocityX, float velocityY) {

    final RelativeLayout detail = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_detail);
    final RelativeLayout photo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_detail_photo);
    final RelativeLayout pod = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_detail_pod);
    final ToggleButton btn_detail = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_detail);
    final ToggleButton btn_pod = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_pod);
    final ToggleButton btn_photo = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_photo);

    // right to left swipe
    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
        Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if((detail.VISIBLE) && (pod.GONE) && (photo.GONE)) {
            detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_photo.setSelected(false);
            btn_pod.setSelected(true);
            btn_detail.setSelected(false);
        }
    }  

    // left to right swipe
    else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
             Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`VISIBLE`, `GONE`, and `INVISIBLE` are static data members on `View`. They are constants. You are treating them like fields or properties of widgets, which is probably not what you want.

I suggest changing:

```
if((detail.VISIBLE) && (pod.GONE) && (photo.GONE))
```

to:

```
if((detail.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) && (pod.getVisibility()==View.GONE) && (photo.getVisibiilty()==View.GONE))
```

Comment: Also, they are `int` values so they can't be tested with a `boolean` statement